# INSERT SQL query with Batch File only

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sql-insert

Is there a way of connecting **and** **inserting** data to a local SQL Server table through a batch file.

The table looks like on the database , ID | compName | availDiskSpace

For example, this would hold the local computer name and available space on the machine.

```
@echo off 
set computerName = computer123 
set diskSpace = 2GB
sqlcmd -S server1\SQLExpress
```

Is it possible to insert these variables to the SQL table with an INSERT, I know i can use SELECT to select data but cantfind anywhere that shows INSERT
.....Thanks

Comment: Insert from what source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign variables using the -v argument for `sqlcmd`. For instance:

```
sqlcmd -S "server1\SQLExpress" -v diskSpace = "2GB" -v computerName = "Computer123" -q "insert into myTable (diskSpace, computerName) select '$(diskSpace)', '$(computerName)'"
```

You declare variables using `-v` and you reference them using `$(<VariableName)`

More detail on `SQLCMD` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

I believe all that should be fine to put in a batch script, but I imagine you can also set batch variables (as you did) and assign those to be the values of the `sqlcmd` variables.

FWIW, this is probably considerably easier to do with SSMS and/or a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Xedni, this makes sense now